# Rotation with indicated degree

Tags: modeling, interface, transforms, edit-mode

Rotation with indicated degree

Basically I have two questions.
 Is it possible to manually specify the rotation step (For example: step = 5 °)
The option in which this value I need to set from the keyboard: Rotation + Y + 5 (45) is not considered.
May be for this purpose is there a special tab?
After reassigning hotkey combination "Ctrl + Rotate / Scale, etc." stopped working.
[image]
Now the "Ctrl" key works with the operation of "Edge Loop Select", and "Shift" with the "Pick Shortest Path"

Is there possible at such a hotkey combination to resume operation "Ctrl + Rotate"?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to rotate by (for example) 5° on the (for example) Y axis every time you hit the (for example) `whatever` key?

Comment: If I rotate the object (Sub-object) using for it manipulator then select one of the axes of rotation (on manipulator!!!), the object moves along the selected axis, but with an arbitrary angle. If, I do, the same actions holding "Ctrl" key, the object rotation happens to exactly a predetermined angle.
it was before (by default).
Now I changed the hotkeys (as described in my first post) and then Ctrl stopped working with rotation.
Шs it possible to return this key combination?

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/z1538fe05/

Answer (score 1):

You may try to reassign the CTRL+R hotkey combination to other hotkey combination
Go to Blender user preferences > Input > search for rotation > and reassign to whatever key combination you want
[image: change key combination CTRL+R]